# Excel: Circular Calculation Won't Converge if In Input in Certain Spatial Layout

Tags: excel, iteration, circular-reference

I've found a bizarre behavior with Excel circular calculations. When enabled (via Options), circular references can be used for iteration. In my example, I'm using [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). The problem I see is when I enter my cell formulas in a certain spatial layout, the iteration **will not** converge. If I use a different layout, **it will converge**. Is it a bug, or am I missing something? Here's how to reproduce it (tested on Excel 2010, 2011):

f(x) = x*ln(x)

1. New Excel Workbook.
2. Create a "horizontal" layout:

   2.1 Make labels. In cells A1-F1, write x_start, x_old, x_new, f(x), f'(x), f-goal

   2.2 Set cell formulas (in this order):

   - A2 =4
   - B2 =IFERROR(C2,A2)
   - C2 =B2-D2/E2
   - D2 =B2*LN(B2)-F2
   - E2 =LN(B2)+1
   - F2 =10
3. Create a "vertical" layout:

   3.1 Make labels. In cells A4-A9, write x_start, x_old, x_new, f(x), f'(x), f-goal

   3.2 Set cell formulas (in this order):

   - B4 =4
   - B5 =IFERROR(B6,B4)
   - B6 =B5-B7/B8
   - B7 =B5*LN(B5)-B9
   - B8 =LN(B5)+1
   - B9 =10
4. Create a "two-column" layout:

   4.1 Make labels. In cells E4-E6, write x_start, x_old, x_new. In cells H4-H6 write f-goal, f(x), f'(x).

   4.2 Set cell formulas (in this order):

   - F4 =4
   - F5 =IFERROR(F6,F4)
   - F6 =F5-G5/G6
   - G5 =F5*LN(F5)-G4
   - G6 =LN(F5)+1
   - G4 =10

The solution should converge for x_old and x_new at about 5.728926, with f(x) being almost zero. Now Press F9 or Shift-F9 to recalculate the cell values. **It only converges for the "two-column" layout** meaning the values don't change (hardly if at all). The horizontal and vertical layouts keep changing numbers randomly and don't get closer to the answer.

You can check the above formulas are exactly the same for the intended variables (verify by  assigning the x_old cell a fixed value for each layout. The numbers will match up perfectly.) I'm I crazy or is this a bug?

Comment: Entering G4:G6 in that order doesn't affect the two-column layout. What's interesting, is you can even drag the cells in the 2-col layout to make a vertical layout, but it doesn't work if you enter the formulas in a vertical layout to start with. Weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Excel uses a different calculation process for circular references.

Cells in the circular loop are calculated left to right and top-to-bottom until the max iterations or change limits are reached.

So this probably why convergence is dependent on spatial arrangement (but I have not looked at your example in detail).

for some more details see 
http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsc.htm